# Why %time output is Wall time: 0 ns in Jupyter Notebook with IPython?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I try to measure query speed in my jupyter notbook

```
%time
a10= pd.read_sql('SELECT t.id, t.order_id FROM transactions.t', con=db_connection)
```

Whatever my query is the output always

```
Wall time: 0 ns
```

I assume  `%time` is not related with previous cell, this cell requires more than 10s to execute, why `Wall time: 0 ns` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have a look at the introduction to [IPython's magics](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#magic-functions); this is a IPython feature, not a Jupyter one.

There is a significant difference between a magic with **One leading percent sign** and a magic with **Two leading percent signs**. The first one applies only to the rest of the line it is on – in your case literally *nothing* —while the latter applies to the rest of the cell.

So you likely want to add a percent in front of your code.

You also most likely want to have a look at [`%timeit/%%timeit`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) which differs from `%time`.